# Confusion about change of bases

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I am confused about a video I just watched about change of bases.
The way I have been understanding change of bases until now is: let's say that I want to express the vector $v=[4, 3]$ into new bases $B=\{(1, 2), (4, 0)\}$, then I would do:

\begin{bmatrix}1&4\\2&0\end{bmatrix}

$$
\left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    1 &  4 \\
    2 &  0\\ 
  \end{array}
\right]
\begin{bmatrix}
           4 \\
           3 \\
         \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
           16 \\
           8 \\
         \end{bmatrix}
$$
So basically arranging each basis as a column vector, which seems clear enough. However I recently watched this video that threw me off completely.
https://www.coursera.org/learn/computational-neuroscience/lecture/5FAT2/change-of-basis-and-pca-by-rich-pang

I hope you can see it, but if not, it's basically claiming that "change of bases" is obtained by arranging each basis as a ROW vector, so that:

$$
\left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    1 &  2 \\
    4 &  0\\ 
  \end{array}
\right]
\begin{bmatrix}
           4 \\
           3 \\
         \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
           10 \\
           16 \\
         \end{bmatrix}
$$

My impression is that the video is mistakenly referring to that procedure as "change of bases", whereas is computing the projection onto the bases (which works nicely only if the bases are normalized). Am I correct? Or am I going through a big misunderstanding?

Thanks

Comment: This is a side-issue but unless you clean up your notation you're bound to get confused. You write your vectors sometimes with $[,]$ sometimes with $(,)$. You start with row vectors and switch them to column vectors without any reason. Consistency is important.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, both methods are wrong. If you want to know how to express $(4,3)$ in the basis $\{(1,2),(4,0)\}$. You compute$$\begin{bmatrix}1&4\\2&0\end{bmatrix}^{-1}.(4,3)=\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac12\\\frac14&-\frac18\end{bmatrix}.(4,3)=\left(\frac32,\frac58\right).$$You can easily check that this is the right answer: if the new coordinates are $a$ and $b$, then$$(4,3)=a(1,2)+b(4,0),$$which is equivalent to$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a+4b=4\\2a=3\end{array}\right.$$and you can easily check that the only solution of this system is $a=\frac32$ and $b=\frac58$.

Comment: thanks, that fixes one misunderstanding. What's the deal with the other video? Is it just wrong or is it wrong in a meaningful way?

Comment: I cannot answer that question, since I haven't watched it. However, if $A$ is an *orthogonal* matrix, then that method works, since then $A^{-1}$ is the transpose of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You took this \begin{bmatrix}1&4\\2&0\end{bmatrix}

but it should be

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&4\\2&0\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$